# When scraping wind speed from Google Weather, I can see it, but can't scrape it

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get wind speeds from the Google 7 day forecast. When I inspect the webpage code I can see the wind speeds but when I use `find_all()` on the class it returns only temperature data and todays wind speed from the 7 day forecast.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.google.co.nz/search?ei=CQmzW9_zHsaiwAPuvruwCQ&q=tauranga+weather+forecast&oq=tauranga++forecast&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i7i30k1l10.9062.9062.0.11810.1.1.0.0.0.0.205.205.2-1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.205....0.R-r6_9AWgnA")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

wind = soup.find_all("span", class_="wob_t")

for i, e in enumerate(wind):
    print(i, e.get_text())
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If the layout changes your app will break. Consider using a weather API instead.

Comment: i'll agree with alexander.. but just for fun do a find_all for div with class "e". you will reach the div where the wind span is

Answer (score 0):

I see that the desired div content what you are looking at is generated by some javascript code. i.e: when you click on the "Wind" button displayed on page, javascript modify the HTML and generate the wind div for 7 days.

With the soup you generated with the given URL, I see there is only a single entry of wind speed div. This is something which is shown on the page.

```
In [7]: soup.findAll("span", text = re.compile("km/h"))
Out[7]: [<span class="wob_t" style="display:inline">16 km/h</span>]
```

So, scraping these type of page which update HTML based on some javascript modification won't be a good idea to scrap using request module. I would suggest accessing these types of the page you should use [python-selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/).

Comment: Ok thanks, I had thought selenium might be outside of my skill level but I'll give it a go. I can see all the wind data for the 7 day forecast in the source code: <span class="wob_t" style="display:inline;text-align:right" aria-label="13 km/h From southwest Wednesday 1:00 AM">13 km/h</span> is this then modified by javascript? Thanks for your help